# Oracle - How to calculate profit that is above average

Tags: sql

I have a table that contains items, buyprice, and sellprice.  I need to figure out how to return which items were sold for a profit above average.  I realize that for each item that I need to calculate sellprice-buyprice to get the profit.  I then need to take the profit from each item and calculate the average profit of all of the items.  I then need to return the items that have profits that are above that average.  I have tried various subselects and I just can't seem to figure out how to return what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems simple enough:

```
SELECT * FROM TBL WHERE sellprice-buyprice > (SELECT AVG(sellprice-buyprice) FROM TBL )
```

Am i missing something?

Comment: Thanks, I was incorrectly trying to do the averaging and greater than before the where clause and it wasn't working.  I am just learning all of this and am still working on my syntax.  I appreciate the help.